# STM32CubeIDE Run Configurations: How to disable 'Set breakpoint at: main' if grayed out

Tags: stm32cubeide

I can't figure out how I have to disable the setting 'Set breakpoint at: main' in the 'Run Configurations' 'Startup' tab. It's grayed out and I can't find it anywhere else. How can this be disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click the project in the "Project Explorer" pane and select "Debug As > Debug Configurations..." from the pop-up menu:

[image]

Comment: This actually works.  I don't get why it's not possible to change the same setting when I go there via 'Project/Properties/...'. Anyhow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of STM32[image]

Things tend to change over time and so did the IDE.